# Compiler not doing anything (new to vba)

Tags: excel, vba, macos

My compile button isn't doing anything at all.

So I'd just figured out how the compiler in VBA works (I've only used C and just started vba today). 
I was fixing my code line by line using the compiler, and then it stopped doing anything. I click it and no message pops up, but no results are appearing (at least where I expect them to). I'm assuming this has something to do with some setting I accidentally messed up or some button I ticked? I have no idea how the coding environment works in vba.

I wonder if something looks off in the screenshots below:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/Fj4m26F]

i would have expected a large amount of files to appear in the folder @ / Users / Karim / Downloads / Word \ files \ 4 \ mom / 
(don't laugh, we all have to be good sons ^^)
but again, nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

When you choose to Compile in VBA, it doesn't create an executable or run the code. From a user perspective, it doesn't effectively do anything more than let you know that there are no compile errors.

You need to actually run the code using the play button. If nothing is happening, use the debug menu to step through the code line by line and take note of when you don't get expected results.

Making the Locals window visible from the View menu makes it easier to monitor variables.

Making the Immediate window visible allows you to run single lines of code independently, including printing the values of variables, changing the values of variables, or printing the results of calculations. For example:

`?1+1`

Comment: sorry for the confusion, the play button is what i've been using to compile. I press the play button and I get feedback. Until it stopped working.

I also tried inserting random letters into the code and running it. Nothing happed :'(

Comment: It just feels like I broke excel

Comment: Have you been using the "Step Into" command from the Debug menu to perform one line of code at a time? Unlike C, you can step through the code and even modify it on the fly, while it is running. You can even drag the execution point to a different line of code if you need to retry something.

Comment: I tried that, and i finally got some sort of error message which was nice, but it raised another question:
https://imgur.com/o0ilbb4
if you take a look at this, does it seem wrong that under module one in the locals window, there are "no variables"?

Comment: Also, i tried using "step into" on a line of code, and in the locals window, a variable given a value of 67 above that line was showing up as 0. Is that a result of the program only compiling that that specific line and ignoring what happened above it?

Comment: Compiling is strange in VBA... when you're stepping through a routine, it will compile the entire routing with every step, so it will always tell you about any syntax errors. But it still performs just one line at a time using the variables in their current state. At each step, it performs whatever the current line says using the current values of all variables. If a variable is changing value, it's because your code is making it change.

Comment: Now, Stack Overflow isn't about teaching you how to program in VBA - there are plenty of websites for that. It's about answering specific questions. If you have a line of code that is making a change to your variables that you don't understand, or you have a line of code that isn't doing what you expect, you can ask a question about that. There's no more information to be given about this particular question, which is just about how to tell if VBA is compiling/running.